# How does Juju "co-exist" with Chef, taking the automation process "one step further"?

Tags: juju

It is clear from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52840/whats-the-difference-between-juju-and-puppet-chef) that Juju sits at a different layer than Chef Server. Juju sits at the orchestration or *service* layer, while Chef sits more at the individual server or *configuration* layer.

At [one of Canonical's main Juju pages](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/orchestration/juju), it states that Juju is designed to "co-exist" with tools like Chef and Puppet, taking the process "one step further". I have scoured the internet for the past several weeks on this subject and cannot find a good explanation of **how** , though, a tool like Chef will **co-exist** with Juju.

So, to breakdown the overarching question in the title: (particular interest in Juju working together with a Chef Server)

- What is an example of a charm "written in Chef"? Is it simply a charm written in bash that then calls the `chef-solo` command? If so, can a charm call the `chef-client` command to work in concert with a Chef Server?
- Where is the overlap between Juju and Chef? For instance, the apache2 charm has its `config-changed` hook where it makes config changes that, in the Chef world, would take place in a recipe by applying a template file. If a Juju charm were to work along with a Chef cookbook on deploying an apache2 service (cluster) it would almost seem that an "apache2-chef" charm would have to be written so that you could separate out the tasks. In this case, the apache2 charm in the Charm Store would be less than helpful.
- If you have Chef roles applied to nodes (service units) that are deployed/managed by Juju and your sysadmin decides to change the firewall rules for a particular server role and does this in the Chef role, is Juju going to ever overwrite those changes?
- More simply, can Juju be a Chef Server wrapper, like [Ironfan](https://github.com/infochimps-labs/ironfan/wiki)?

I view Chef Server as the *how* whereas Juju can do the *how*, but also brings *what* to the table. Meaning that the real current state of services and machines can be queried and acted upon. You can't do this in Chef Server. My goal is to bring Juju's awareness and service orchestration capability into a Chef Server-managed infrastructure.

It almost seems that a whole set of charms would have to be written where all Chef-managed tasks/config info are left out.

I would love to hear weigh-ins from someone at Canonical (like Jorge Castro) and from Opscode (like A. Jacob or J. Timberman).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

awesome questions!

#### the tl;dr

I'd like to break your question(s) down over a couple of comments... first off, here're
a couple of general approaches to integrating chef and juju:

- charms hooks can use existing chef recipes that run solo-style on service
  units (recommended)
- juju service units register with an existing chef-server using a chef-node subordinate
  service

These ideas **haven't been implemented**/tested yet for chef, but the puppet
equivalents exist.

#### the... um.. not-so-short answer

Here's a little more of a breakdown of two approaches to integrating chef and juju:

### Juju as top-dog

Here juju runs the show.  The biggest value juju provides is event coordination
during distributed configuration management... hence the "service
orchestration" moniker.  Juju charms consist of hooks which are called by juju
at "the right time" when coordinating service management.  The implementation
of these hooks is pretty much open.  They're shell scripts, source code, puppet
manifests, or... chef recipes.

Juju breaks bits of any service config up into:

- "installation".. the bits that're specific to installing a particular service
  onto a node
- "relation".. the bits of config that're needed to relate that service to some
  other service

The key to using chef recipes as hook implementations is exactly this... you
have to make sure that the recipes you're using respect this separation of
concerns.  Otherwise, there's nothing that prevents using off-the-shelf
cookbooks.  You can leverage existing recipes you've spent time/money to develop.... You
just need to make sure you can call the relation-specific stuff separately from
the installation-specific stuff.

We need some examples of this, but I think it'll be popular b/c chef has a
great dsl, a great templating tool, and is much more pleasant to use than bash
when writing complex config.  For simple config, chef recipes are a little
overkill imo, so this method of integration is pretty much the best of both
worlds... and has serious legs going forward.

### Chef as top-dog

The idea here is to integrate juju services into an existing chef-server
managed infrastructure.  To do this, you'd need to write a chef-node
subordinate charm.  This subordinate service would be attached to primary juju
services and would effectively register these services as nodes (in particular
roles) with the chef server.  Subs can be attached during juju service startup,
or anytime later throughout each service's lifecycle.

I'm thinking this'd be quite similar to the puppet-node sub.  All necessary
keys, roles, etc would be specified via config to the chef-node subordinate
charm.  I'd start there.  A more sophisticated approach would be for the
chef-node sub to interrogate both the primary service it's attached to and its
chef-server to dynamically determine roles, but that'd be quite a bit harder
than just specifying them in config for the sub.

### Opinions

I'd definitely recommend method 1 above, if possible.  Having the coordination layer on *top* of the configuration tools will probably work well long-term.  Needless to say, real-world infrastructures might be some combo or variation of both approaches for a period of time...  especially during migration.    Planned coexistance using method 2 would probably only work if the components managed by both tools were somewhat orthogonal to each other.  Not sure exactly what that would look like.  Perhaps juju and chef manage separate relatively decoupled services?  I suspect it might work well to let juju manage primary services and have chef manage more infrastructure aspects.  Dunno.  That's a bit of a longer discussion though :)

Side note... you can also use juju to manage chef-server itself... even large
complex multi-tier chef-server installations.  I haven't looked at the
chef-server charm lately, but if it doesn't currently handle tiering and
separation of services, then it can certainly be made to.

I'd love to see more examples of both types of chef integration mentioned
above... it's been on my wish / todo list for a while, but has yet to bubble up
high enough in priority to get done...  please help if you're interested!

ok, that's a decent chunk of rambling :)... let's start there, then we can go into more detail in subsequent comment blocks.

Comment: great stuff here.

"I suspect it might work well to let juju manage primary services and have chef manage more infrastructure aspects."

This is what I'm really interested in, as we share this same suspicion. Like you said, Chef's DSL and templating are great for configuration. However, there are other aspects of Chef Server (data bags) that would be hard to let go of, in your first method.

Juju, being at service level, should be top dog, but I feel it should allow Chef to do what it does best in the Chef Server model. Must work for both devs and admins. But perhaps no need for Chef Server.