# Kubernetes : for application deployment, how do Juju Charms compare to Helm charts?

Tags: juju, kubernetes

What are pros/cons in using a Juju Charm rather than a [Helm chart](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kubernetes-helm/info) to deploy an application over a Kubernetes cluster ? It seems to do quite the same job, for instance for a Wordpress deployment ?

Comment: This is actually on-topic, and I have the same question.  jujucharms.com is owned by Canonical, and the "Connect" section at https://jujucharms.com/community sends users to http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/juju, and the OP has tagged his question appropriately.  The question should be reopened.  @andrea-lazzarotto

Comment: Further, https://askubuntu.com/questions/52840/whats-the-difference-between-juju-and-puppet-chef asks a very similar question and is not considered off-topic.